# Pandas Groupby Percentage of total

Tags: python, pandas

```
    df["% Sales"] = df["Jan"]/df["Q1"]
    q1_sales =  df.groupby(["City"])["Jan","Feb","Mar", "Q1"].sum()
    ql_sales.head()



                   Jan  Feb  Mar   Q1
City            
Los Angeles        44   40   54   138
```

Want the code to get the percentage of sales for the quarter. Want it to look like this below each month is divided by the total sales of the quarter.

```
                     Jan    Feb   Mar  
City            
Los Angeles          31.9%  29%  39.1%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `div`:

```
q1_sales[['Jan','Feb','Mar']].div(q1_sales['Q1']*0.01, axis='rows')
```

Output:

```
                   Jan        Feb        Mar
City                                        
Los Angeles  31.884058  28.985507  39.130435
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
new_df=q1_sales[q1_sales.columns.difference(['Q1'])]
new_df=(new_df.T/new_df.sum(axis=1)*100).T
print(new_df)

                   Feb        Jan        Mar
Los Angeles  28.985507  31.884058  39.130435
```

Comment: i'd add `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}%'.format` to match his format